# Union two arrays in PHP with the same structure

Tags: php, arrays

There is a way to union/merge two arrays on PHP like this example?

My arrays:

```
$A = Array(
    0=>array(
            'type' => "t1",
            'name'=>"John",
    ),
    1=>array(
            'type' => "t1",
            'name'=>"Jane",
    )
);

$B = Array(
    0=>array(
            'surname' => "Doe",
    ),
    1=>array(
            'surname' => "Black",
    )
);
```

Result like this one:

```
$Merged = Array(
    0=>array(
            'type' => "t1",
            'name'=>"John",
            'surname' => "Doe",
    ),
    1=>array(
            'type' => "t1",
            'name'=>"Jane",
            'surname' => "Black",
    )
);
```

Array A and B have always the same size and are populated from the DB. Unfortunatelly I can't merge with a query and I need split before and merge after.

Comment: I am sure u can join both array within your SQL query unless it come from different source

Comment: Assuming all your arrays are in order then `foreach($A as $b => $a) var_dump($a + $B[$b])` would be the most efficient way to sum union the 2D array. It's way more efficient than an array merge solution, but I agree with zimorok that the SQL query rewrite is worth a go.

Comment: thanks for all suggestions. At The end my problem it was some faulty data in my DB. For this reason, when I tried to get a lot of subquery (+100) in one select, my code broke up and I tried this workaround. Now I fix my data and all workly perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). By the way, indexes `0` and `1` are redundant at `$a` and `$b` in this example.

```php
<?php

$a = [
    0 => [
        'type' => "t1",
        'name' => "John",
    ],
    1 => [
        'type' => "t1",
        'name' => "Jane",
    ]
];

$b = [
    0 => [
        'surname' => "Doe",
    ],
    1 => [
        'surname' => "Black",
    ]
];

$c = [];

// Assuming that count of $a and $b are equal.

for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); ++$i) {
    $c[$i] = array_merge($a[$i], $b[$i]);
}

print_r($c);
```